# How to set contents of a table view in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I am a complete newbie to iOS development but not to programming.

I am trying to create a simple application. I have opened Xcode 4.2 and created a new master view application. What I want to do is to set the contents of the table view in the master page.

I have edited my controller header file like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyAppMasterViewController : UITableViewController

{
    NSArray *tableViewArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *tableViewArray;

@end
```

I have synthesized the tableViewArray variable in the controller implementation:

```
#import "MyAppMasterViewController.h"

@implementation MyAppMasterViewController

@synthesize tableViewArray;
```

And I have loaded an NSArray isntance into it in viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple", @"Microsoft", @"HTC", nil];
    self.tableViewArray = array;
}
```

How can I, now, assign this array (tableViewArray) to the table view?

Comment: I recommend the Stanford iOS videos on iTunes U, they explain how this works very well.

Comment: very much worth doing some introductory tutorials before posting for help. A simple google for "UITableView tutorial" returns a ton of links that would answer this question and more. The top hit looks promising http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I, now, assign this array (tableViewArray) to the table view?

You don't 'assign' an array to a table, you use some magic with delegates.  Conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` in your .h like so:

```
@interface MyAppMasterViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
```

**Assign your class as the delegate** (most likely in -viewDidLoad) for the table: then, your table view will query you for the all important -cellForRowAtIndexPath method, in which you set the title of the cell with something like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_documentTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return ( cell );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't. The table view asks you for the cells that go in the table view one by one as they are needed. The table view also asks how many cells there are and how many sections there are and a whole load of other stuff about how it behaves.

How does the table view know what instance to ask this information from? It has a property called delegate. You set the delegate on your table view to your viewController instance and then choose to implement which ever methods you need from the `UITableViewDatasource` protocol in your view controller instance.

read more about delegation and properties in Objective-C